# Minimising the MSE(\sigma^{2}_{m}) by differentiation

Tags: statistics, derivatives, optimization

I'm supposed to find the value of $m$ that minimises the MSE$(\hat{\sigma}^{2}_{m})$ that is defined as

$$\frac{2(n-k)\sigma^{4}}{m^{2}}+\bigg(\frac{(n-k)\sigma^{2}}{m}- \sigma^{2}\bigg )^{2}$$

I rewrote this:

$$\frac{2(n-k)\sigma^{4}}{m^{2}}+ \frac{(n-k-m)^{2}\sigma^{4}}{m^{2}} = \frac{\sigma^{4}(2(n-k)+(n-k-m)^{2})}{m^{2}}$$

Then differentiating this with respect to $m$ gave me:
$$\frac{-2\sigma^{4}(2(n-k)+(n-k-m)^{2})}{m^{3}} = \frac{2\sigma^{4}(2(k-n)-(n-k-m)^{2})}{m^{3}}$$

However the answer was:
$$\frac{2\sigma^{4}(k-n)(k-n+m-2)}{m^{3}}$$

I tried moving stuff around to get to the answer but it did not work, so I think I differentiated it wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take derivative directly:
$$\left[\frac{2(n-k)\sigma^{4}}{m^{2}}+\bigg(\frac{(n-k)\sigma^{2}}{m}- \sigma^{2}\bigg )^{2}\right]'=\\
-\frac{4(n-k)\sigma ^4}{m^3}+2\left(\frac{(n-k)\sigma^{2}}{m}- \sigma^{2}\right)\cdot \left(-\frac{(n-k)\sigma ^2}{m^2}\right)=\\
\frac{4(k-n)\sigma ^4}{m^3}+\frac{2(k-n)(n-k-m)\sigma ^4}{m^3}=\\
\frac{2(k-n)[2+n-k-m]\sigma ^4}{m^3},$$
which is sign-different from your answer.